# UUID "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"346ob2dc-8a11-47f1-b3a5-bcKe63aeeddf\" (type string) at path \"user\" because of \"BSONTypeError\""

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, uuid

Created a nested route for my Express App.
But, it's given me BSON Type Error whenever I run the code.

```
exports.setUserIds = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.user) req.body.user = req.user.id;
  next();
};

exports.createQuestion = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const doc = await Question.create(req.body);

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      data: doc,
    },
  });
});
```

Using uuid version 8.3.2

Comment: Can you post the `Question` schema declaration and a log of the `req.body`?

Comment: I later figured it out. I was declaring the id in the Question schema as mongoose.Schema.ObjectId instead of just String.